# Why do market makers sometimes quote absurd bid and ask prices rather than remove their quotes?

Tags: stocks, bid-ask, quotes, securities, market-making

The image below shows the Level 2 bids for Fortescue Metals Group Ltd (OTCQX: [FSUMF](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/FSUMF/overview)) on 2020-10-07 10:20 am:

[image: FSUMF Level 2 bids on 2020-10-07 10:20 am]

Notice the 0.01 × 10,000 bid by NITE (Virtu Americas LLC), which is extremely unlikely to be matched. What's the reason for placing a bid at an absurd price? Why don't market makers simply cancel their orders instead?

I've noticed this practice — market markers placing very low bids or very high asks — in many securities, so I think this is a rather common practice.

I understand that the minimum quotation size in this case is a function of the bid price (according to [FINRA rule 6433. Minimum Quotation Size Requirements For OTC Equity Securities](https://www.finra.org/rules-guidance/rulebooks/finra-rules/6433)), so my question is more about the $0.01 bid price rather than the 10,000 bid size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These "absurd bid and ask prices" are called "stub quotes".

> A stub quote is an offer to buy or sell a stock at a price so far away from the prevailing market that it is not intended to be executed, such as an order to buy at a penny or an offer to sell at $100,000. **A market maker may enter stub quotes to nominally comply with its obligation to maintain a two-sided quotation at those times when it does not wish to actively provide liquidity.**

([source](https://www.sec.gov/news/press/2010/2010-216.htm))

In the USA, market makers are not allowed to enter stub quotes on Regulation NMS stocks during regular trading hours. This rule was introduced after the [2010 flash crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_flash_crash). The relevant SEC press release: [SEC Approves New Rules Prohibiting Market Maker Stub Quotes](https://www.sec.gov/news/press/2010/2010-216.htm).

However, FSUMF is an over-the-counter stock; it is not an exchange-traded stock covered by Regulation NMS. Therefore, the regulations described above do not apply, so market makers are free to enter stub quotes for this stock.

Comment: ,this is a **GREAT** answer!  Thanks for being so thorough!

Comment: There's one problem with this answer: market makers for OTC stocks have no obligation to maintain continuous two-sided markets. There is no rule that prevents the market maker from cancelling the quote. Perhaps TomTom's answer is correct: the stub quote exists because of quirks in the market maker's in-house software.

Comment: just because they are not required to does not mean they do not.  When I worked in investment banking, we specialized in otc stocks, and it wascommon to see this.

Answer (score 3):

First, MM's are bound to provide quotes within specific parameters by contract. ONE of those parameters is time (95% of the time, i.e.).

Second, this could be just a bet (maybe someone sells market - it DOES happen, MM's often keep far away orders for cases like that) or.... a software issue (not able to handle a 0 price "properly" and thus providing a quote for the smallest possible price) - on the MM side.

Comment: "this could be just a bet..." What does this mean? Who is betting? Betting on what?

Comment: Well, if the order ois from a market maker, grade school logic would tell you it is the market maker betting.

Comment: What is the market maker betting on? Is the market maker worried that there is an upcoming large sell order will take out all the bids above it?

Comment: Exactly. And I know people who make quite some money with that - though at a lot of work (which can be automated).

Comment: How does it work? Place a large sell order, take out all the bids, scare all the market participants, ... ??? ..., and profit? Could you explain the steps? Thank you.

Comment: Let's ignore the one cent bid.  In illiquid stocks, traders pull their quotes at the end of the day.  The market maker remains with a really wide B/A spread quote.  During after hours, occasionally someone makes a fat finger trade and overpays or undersells.  This happens more frequently in a fast market like 2008 or last March when it was hitting the fan.